# returning an async value is returning "undefined" - why can't I return a value?

Tags: javascript, react-native, for-loop, asynchronous, async-await

I am returning a value from one class/function to another.

class 1:

```
const updateLikedQueue  = (dispatch) => {
return  async (likedId)=>{
    try{
        const response = await config.updateUserData(likedId, 'liked');
        const matchResponse = await config.lookForMatches(likedId);
        console.log('matchResponse> ' + matchResponse);//undefined
        dispatch({type: 'update_user_liked_data', payload: response});
        if(matchResponse){
            dispatch({type: 'update_user_matches_data', payload: likedId});
            return 'You have a match!'
        }
    } catch(e){
        dispatch({type: 'add_error', payload: '' + e}); 
    }
}
};
```

class 2:

```
lookForMatches = async (likedId) => {
var db = firebase.firestore();
var users = db.collection("Users");
var currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;
var response = users.where('liked', 'array-contains', currentUser.uid);
response.get().then( function (querySnapshot) {
  var match = false;
  querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
      var docData = doc.data();
      if (docData.id == likedId) {
        console.log('you have a match');
        match = true;
      }
  })
  return match;
})
```

}

but the `matchresponse` is always coming in as undefined no matter how I try to pass a value. I have tried passing a string, changing the loop to a regular for loop, breaking the loop, returning with in the loop, making the "lookForMatches" callback async. I am not sure why this isn't working. Normally I am able to just pass back the value while I "await" for it to complete. what am I doing wrong here?

PS I can console.log "you have a match" so I know it is working.

Comment: `lookForMatches` isn't returning anything. You need to make it return the promise `response.get()....`

Comment: You need to `return response.get().then(...)`, otherwise it's not part of the chain.

Comment: ah thank you. I thought that by breaking the loop or returning outside of the loop I was able to return. I updated the entire method to return the value and it is working now. Thank you!! If you want to update with an answer I will mark it correct

Comment: You're returning outside the forEach loop, but you're still only returning inside the `.then()` callback instead of from the overall `lookForMatches` function :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lookForMatches` isn't returning anything. You need to make it return the promise `response.get()`. You're returning outside the forEach loop, but you're still only returning inside the `.then()` callback instead of from the overall `lookForMatches` function :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `lookforMatches` function doesn't `return` anything, that  `return` keyword is inside the callback to `.then(…)`. You should drop that and use `await` instead:

```
async function lookForMatches(likedId) {
  const db = firebase.firestore();
  const users = db.collection("Users");
  const currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;
  const response = users.where('liked', 'array-contains', currentUser.uid);
  const querySnapshot = await response.get();
  var match = querySnapshot.docs.some(doc => {
    var docData = doc.data();
    return docData.id == likedId;
  });
  if (match) console.log('you have a match');
  return match;
}
```